# which one should i choose, subclassing or categories

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, categories, subclassing

I have UIlabel and includes few customisation of it . and this label is used in so many screens in my application. i tried with both subclassing and categories in prototype. 
which is preferred one to use in this case. subclassing or categories.

Answer (score 2):

Scenario - 1 : If you want to change something which happens as part of framework calls during the lifecycle of a UI object? - use **subclass**.

Scenario - 2 : If you want something application wide, something which is in addition to the existing functionality, and you don't care if this becomes available to all instances of this pre-existing instances of the framework class?  - use **categories**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Subclassing` instead of `category`. `Category` should be used when you want to alter the behavior of every instance of class while `Subclassing` should be used when you want to alter behavior of specific instance or objects.

Category is harmful also in some cases as you are manipulation existing class so it is better to use `Subclassing` where possible!!

Comment: i think categories and subclassing explanation u told reverse.

Comment: ignore my previous comment. sorry.